# EventEmitter not emitted when called in subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, eventemitter

I try to pass a form from my child component to his parent.

Child TS:

```
@Output() submit: EventEmitter<FormGroup> = new EventEmitter();

updateStream(): void {
    const body = {some data};

    // If I put this.submit.emit(this.form) here it works

    this.apiGatewayService.verifyKeys(body).subscribe(
       (res) => {
        console.log('SUCCESS verify : ', res);
        this.submit.emit(this.form); // doesn't work
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('ERROR verify : ', error);
        this.disableLoader.emit(); // doesn't work
      });
}
```

The html :

```
<child (submit)="updateStream($event)"></child>
```

Parent TS :

```
 updateStream(form: formGroup): void {
    console.log('UPDATE');
  }
```

All my emits into subscribe doesn't work (console.log in parent composant not displayed). However outside the subscribe it works.

Have you an idea ?

**EDIT**

the problem is with the line this.apiGatewayService.verifyKeys(body). This call works perfectly (correct response), however the emit doesn't work. However, it works, if I mock this call like this :

```
updateStreamOut(): void {
    this.test().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log('SUCCESS verify : ', res);
        this.submit.emit(this.lambdaForm); // Works
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('ERROR verify : ', error);
        this.verifyError = true;
        this.disableLoader.emit(); // Works
      }
    );
  }

  test(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of({ status: 'ok' });
  }
```

Here my function verifyKeys :

```
verifyKeys(body): Observable<any> {
    const result = Observable.fromPromise(
      this.client.externalVerifyPost({}, body, config.additionalParams)
    );

    return this.handleResult.dispatchResponse(result, false);
  }
```

HandleResult service :

```
 dispatchResponse(result: Observable<any>, enableSnackbar: boolean = true) {
    return result
      .catch((error) => {
        const exception = this.getException(error);

        this.apiResponse.errorsHandler(exception);
        return Observable.throw(exception);
      })
      .mergeMap((res) => {
        if (enableSnackbar) {
          this.apiResponse.successHandler(res);
        }
        return Observable.of(res.data);
      });
  }
```

Maybe it gives you more informations.

Comment: Are you sure the `subscribe` handlers are even called? Can you make a demo?

Comment: Yes the console.log into the subscribe (success or failed) are correctly displayed. Moreover the request to the backend pass correctly too :/

Comment: @onedkr this code looks correct and should work. As asked, you could create a demo to showcase the issue.

Comment: this.apiGatewayService.verifyKeys(body) not firing

Comment: I edit my post. the problem is with the call apiGatewayService.verifyKeys(body), but I still don't understand what is incorrect

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found my error. Indeed, when this.apiGatewayService.verifyKeys(body) was launch a loader was displayed.

My parent HTML was build like this :

```
<div *ngIf="!loader">
    <child ...></child
</div>

<div *ngIf="loader>
    My loader
</div>
```

So when my loader was display, my component was delete from the DOM and my "submit" event emitter was unsubscribe.

To prevent that, I use the angular property [hidden] instead of *ngIf. [Hidden] act like a display: none, and not delete my child component from the DOM.

Comment: I am facing the same issue (event emitted before the subscribe, but randomly not within the subscribe), however my DOM elements are not conditioned by anything. So any suggestion would be welcome!